# How Angular assign scope when we dynamic add DOM element in it

Tags: angularjs, scope

All:

I am pretty new to Angular Directive, from API doc:
https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/ng/function/angular.element

> scope() - retrieves the scope of the current element or its parent.
>   Requires Debug Data to be enabled.

And say I have a directive like:

```
.directive("test", function($compile){
    return {
         restrict: "AE",
         scope: { data: "=" },
         replace:true,
         template:"<div id='viz'></div>",
         link: function(scope, EL, attrs){
               console.log(angular.element(EL).scope(), EL);
               console.log(scope);
         }
    }
})
```

And HTML like:

```
<body ng-controller="main">  
    <test></test>
</body>
```

One interesting thing is:

The two scopes printed out in console are not same scope, I wonder why this happens?
If like the API doc says: `scope()` will return current element's scope, if not, then its parent's. I think they both should return the isolate scope of test, but why `angular.element(EL).scope()` return its parent's scope?

Thanks

Comment: You should use [isolateScope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#methods) when getting the scope of a directive defined with isolated scope

Comment: You don't need to use `angular.element().scope()` except in very rare cases and typically outside of angular. Forget it even exists for now. It's not something you will need right away. Have noticed in several previous questions that you are thinking about the DOM first... that's not how you think when using angular. Forget the DOM .... let angular manage it for you based on your data models

Comment: Also ...can inspect angular scope in dev tools

Comment: @ user2341963 Thanks, could you show me a fiddle how to use isoLateScope? I am so confused why it is different from scope in directive link function

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks, well, I guess my question is why those two outputs in console are different scopes rather than if I should use angular.element().scope() or not. Could you help with why these two scope is different?

Comment: scope of an element may not be the full scope of controller or isolated scope either due to nature of nesting and child scopes and isolated scopes. You should really spend the time to properly read and understand: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes. Trying to explain in a short answer is not viable

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, in my example, I think it is totally an isolated Scope,  I wonder what else scope involves in my example inside that directive? I thought for each isolated scope directive, there should be only one scope applies, other value can only be passed in via attributes, event message etcs but not another scope applied to it

Comment: There is no way you read that scope document I linked to already. It is really important to understanding how to work with angular

Comment: @charlietfl thanks, I thought I read that post before, but not thoroughly(like word by word), could you help point out which part on that page related to this example's reason why these two scope outputs are different?

Comment: No.. I can't. That means I need to read through it myself...find appropriate spots and label them.....when you should be the one reading it

Comment: There are also lots of other less technical explanations around ...should be easy to find in google

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, thanks